# if __name__ != __main__:

Tags: python, flask

I just started to learn Flask, and I'm a little bit confused about the code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
print(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(__name__)   # I add two more lines here
  print("ok")
  app.run()
```

The filename is app.py. When I use the command `python app.py`in terminal, the result is

```
__main__
__main__
ok
...flask running information...
```

But when I run the code in PyCharm, what I got is:

```
...flask running information...
app
```

If I modify the code like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
print(__name__)
if __name__ != '__main__':
  print(__name__)   # I add two more lines here
  print("ok")
  app.run()
```

The result is:

```
...flask running information...
app
app
ok
```

And I did this in the terminal, the flask would not start and the result is:

```
__main__
```

So how come _ *name* _ equals '_ *main* _' in the terminal and _ *name* _ does not equal '_ *main* _' in the PyCharm and the flask was running under both circumstances in PyCharm but not the same in the command line?

[image: PyCharm run configure screenshot]

Comment: What's your pycharm run configuration? Could you maybe screenshot it and add it to the post?

Comment: Do you mean the environment and interpreter?

Comment: It looks like you're running this as a flask app in your IDE, rather than as a standard python program. That's why your output is different.

Comment: Could you give me some pointers about how to handle this?

Comment: In your configuration settings, on the left, make sure it's set to `Python`.